# EXCEPTION - bad allocation-printing

Tags: qgis, printing

I have a street map, from Durango, Mexico, and I want to print it. But QGIS show the next error "EXCEPTION bad allocation". I'm going to print it in 1.50 x 1.06 mts sheet.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Your printing task is just too big for the print composer.

There were several bug reports about that, and the issue might be solved in QGIS 2.0 which will be out soon.

Comment: Thak you! Have a nice day.